# Салют прямоугольниками с произвольным текстом внутри

Tags: c

Привет всем. Помогите решить задачку.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define path"C:\\TEMP\\BGI"

main()
{
    int gb = DETECT, gm, i, x, y, r, n, c, c1, x1, x2, y1, y2.intgraph(&gb, &gm, path);
    for (i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
    {
        x = rand() % 460;
        y = rand() % 300;
        r = rand() % 50;
        n = rand() % 120;
        c = rand() % 15;
        setfillstyle(n, c);
        c1 = c + 1;
        setcolor(c1);
        circle(x, y, r);
        floodfill(x, y, c11)
    }
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Нужно, чтоб эта прога строила салют прямоугольниками с произвольным текстом внутри. Я уже 3 часа голову ломаю, сообразить ничего не могу, помогите пожалуйста, кто знает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем! Кто хотя бы попытался мне помочь, но я уже сам справился=). Кому интересно    посмотрите:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define path "C:\\BORLANDC\\BGI"

main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm, i, x, y, r, n, c, c1, x1, x2, y1, y2;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, path);
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        x1 = rand() % 500;
        y1 = rand() % 400;
        r = rand() % 100;
        x2 = x1 + r;
        y2 = y1 + r;
        n = rand() % 12;
        c = rand() % 15;
        setfillstyle(n, c);
        bar(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        x = (x1 + x2) / 2 - 15;
        y = (y1 + y2) / 2;
        c1 = c + 1;
        setcolor(c1);
        outtextxy(x, y, "ya lublu borsh'");
    }
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

А в каком месте программы у вас, конкретно, возникло сомнение в её работе?

Comment: По моему, в таком виде она даже не компилируется.

Comment: To @insolor, я имел в виду int DETECT,...,**y2.intgraph**(&gb, &gm, path);

Интересно, почему комментарий переехал из вопроса в ответ ?

Comment: Про компиляцию я уже понял.
Коммент наверное перенесен ХешКодом.